# How can I timing in verilog from ns to s?

Tags: verilog

How can I change a number per second on a digital display in verilog?
Before the header appear "timescale 1ns / 1ps ".
So when I write "#1 ... " this is 1ns.
How I could write to appear the number per second without write "#1000000000"?

```
always @(*)
    begin
    if(binary_input==0)
    begin
    seg=8'b10011111; /*1*/
    #100 seg=8'b00001001; /*9*/
    #100 seg=8'b00001101;
```

Comment: Is this to to synthesize or just simulate?

Comment: It is for synthesize.

Comment: Delays like this are not synthesizable.

Comment: The synthesize was checked . I want to show on my display : 1 ( pause 1 second ) 2 ( pause one second ) 3 (pause one second ) ... and I want to know how to change the timing..

Comment: What do you think `#1` gets synthesised to? have you tried using `#1ns`, `#1s` for your behavioural model.

Comment: I can't try before 30 March , because i don't have access in laboratory. So I want to know how it work.
But the "timescale " must to change it ? like "timescale 1s (unit) / 1ms ( precision ) ?

Comment: It doesn't work #1s : "Line 36: Syntax error near "=". "

Comment: If you do not have access to a lab then try a free simulator or an online one like http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Rn . The `#1s` is SystemVerilog and most simulators support this try `-sv` command line flags or changing file extension to `.sv` to enable support.

Comment: I try another method. I have a clock on the board with 50MHz.
Now i try to do like
/* always @(posedge clock)
    
   begin
   if(binary_input==0)
   forever begin
   seg=8'b10011111; /*1*/
    seg=8'b00001001; /*9*/                 seg=8'b00001101;/*3*/  
seg=8'b00000011/*0*/ ; end end*/ 
But now i don't know how to convert the clock from 50MHz to 1hz to count per second.

Answer (score 0):

Delays such as `#10` and `#1us` are not synthesizable. These delays are used for test benches and non-synthesizable behavioral models (a.k.a. reference models) such as clock generators.

In a synthesizable design, time is measured in number of clock cycles. To has your design wait a specific amount of time, a counter that can store a value of desired time divided by the clock period. For example, 1 second on a 100 nano-second clock requires a counter that can store a value of 10,000,000.

Comment: I try another method. I have a clock on the board with 50MHz. Now i try to do like /* always @(posedge clock) begin if(binary_input==0) forever begin seg=8'b10011111; /*1*/ seg=8'b00001001; /*9*/ seg=8'b00001101;/*3*/ seg=8'b00000011/*0*/ ; end end*/ But now i don't know how to convert the clock from 50MHz to 1hz to count per second.

Comment: `forever` is not synthesizable either. Where is your synchronous counter?

Comment: `code`module show(input clock,output reg reset,reg [25:0] count,output reg [7:0] seg,output reg [3:0] cnp  
    );             
always @(posedge clock)
begin
if(count==50000000) begin
count <= 1;
cnp <= cnp + 1;
reset <= 1;end
else begin
count <= count + 1;
reset <= 0 ;end end ;
always @(cnp) begin
case(cnp)
1: seg=8'b10011111; /*1*/
2: seg=8'b00001001; /*9*/
3: seg=8'b00001101; /*3*/
4: seg=8'b00000011; 
5: seg=8'b10011001; 
6: seg=8'b10011111; 
7: seg=8'b10011001; ..8 9 10 11 12
13: seg=8'b10011111; 
14: seg=8'b11111111;
15: seg=8'b11111111; /*sleep*/ endcase end
 endmodule